# Quick Question - Hot Reboot - Android

Tags: reboot

Can anyone please tell me what is the difference between the a normal Android boot vs. a hot reboot!? When I toggle the power options on my tablet to turn it off or reboot it... It says on the bottom "hot reboot"!? I have looked it up online, and nothing has giving me an understatement of the difference. Nothing clearly defines it. That would be great thank you! :)

Comment: To quote [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reboot_(computing)), *reboots can be either cold (alternatively known as hard) where the power to the system is physically turned off and back on again, causing an initial boot of the machine, or warm (alternatively known as soft) where the system restarts without the need to interrupt the power*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cold boot means start a machine from a state where its power is not supplied, and a cold (hard) reboot means completely shut down power then power up as a normal boot. In a cold boot procedure, the BIOS first starts after the machine gets powered, loading the system's loader before actually starting the operating system.
On the contrary, a hot reboot does *not* cut the power to a machine, but simply shuts down the running OS and re-load it. No hardware components lose their power during a hot reboot. Only the system works *as if* it's normally booted.

Answer (score -2):

There are certain software components that don't need to be reloaded to "restart" Android OS. So the hot restart is when only the needed components are reloaded.
You can see it in action if you use the RootTools Android library(developing on Android Studio) with the following code:

```
RootTools.restartAndroid();
```