# Samsung reboots daily, but 'uptime' says otherwise

Tags: samsung, reboot, soft-reboot, samsung-galaxy-a20

I'm pretty sure my Samsung Galaxy A20 reboots daily, at around the same time, showing the usual signs of a reboot: sounds some kind of notification it's rebooted, takes a few seconds to find the SIM and reload the weather widget, asks for the password instead of a fingerprint to log in ("after a reboot").

However, `Settings/About Phone/Status/Uptime` says it's been up for weeks.

What's going on with it? Is it just reloading part of the OS? Is this normal? Why is it rebooting daily?

Comment: Uptime (as exported in `/proc/uptime` and as in [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-11.0.0_r1/packages/SettingsLib/src/com/android/settingslib/deviceinfo/AbstractUptimePreferenceController.java#92)) changes only if kernel restarts. The signs of a reboot you've described may occur even if only Java stack is restarted i.e. Android framework has performed a [soft reboot](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/219876/218526).

Comment: @IrfanLatif I think the big questions are why would it be doing this, and is this normal?  What do you think?

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket why is it restarting? No it's not normal. Might be a bug. And bugs have many possible reasons, in fact countless. `logcat` (or `pstore` in case of kernel panic) usually helps to trace the root cause. But apparently this isn't the main question OP asked about.

Comment: @IrfanLatif Thanks.  I've never heard of it for a Samsung phone, but I wanted to make sure it wasn't some sort of weird Samsung thing.  Over the years, I've had various devices that intentionally auto-restart at a certain point, but IIRC, never an Android phone.  I think some of the Android-based TV boxes may auto-reboot once in a while though.

Comment: do another reboot yourself and check uptime